# Spoof Captive Portal Screen on an iOS Device using DNS

Tags: ios, dns, captivenetwork

I want to be able to open a captive screen on an IOS device, when the user enters my DNS number in his network settings.

From what I've seen the iOS device, calls the URL : captive.apple.com . If it received a response, it doesn't open the captive window as it believes the network is working without any limit. However if it isn't able to pull open this URL, it opens the captive portal window.

Remember I don't want a local regular WiFi network with a login . I want to spoof devices when they try to reach my DNS, by blocking all packets.

I just want to open my captive portal splash screen automatically when my DNS is entered.

How can this be done with PHP.

Comment: Please, answer a few questions to clarify your scenario: **1)** What is your network topology? **2)** Which device/model are you using as router/switch? **3)** How do you identify whether a client is authorised to access the internet or not? **--** Finally, PHP will only play a role in the authorisation/authentication step, unless you're creating the overall mechanism to run inside a router/switch device.

Comment: Hey i dont want for this to have anything to do with a router or anything. I want to spoof iOS into opening the captive window as it believes the connection requires it.

Comment: Ok, so I assume you'll do spoofing directly on the WiFi. Is that correct? Are you able to sniff the network? In order to inject valid DNS (non-DNSSEC) response packets: 1) Sniff DNS requests; 2) Reply with fake (but valid) answer entries using the spoofed address of the original DNS destination and the corresponding ID of the request. -- What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, what ive tried is just tampering around with the DNS settings of my domain. I made the address: captive.apple.com, redirect to an IP path: XX.XX.XX.XX/login. I dont know how to sniff dns requests. Ive just read that is the iOS device detects that packets are being blocked, it will open up the page authorized by the server in a captive portal

Comment: The captive portal mechanism is not that simple. IIRC, iOS > 6 tries to fetch 7 or 8 different URLs before assuming the internet is inaccessible & presents the portal page. If the device is able to connect to any of these, it WILL NOT show the captive portal page. Even if you manage to block access to the related domains (which includes apple.com, therefore a terrible idea), the device still needs to know WHAT is the address of the captive portal. This is something you can do with a DHCP server, or an HTTP proxy server, or ultimately injecting packets (much harder & less reliable).

Comment: Yes I've read that somewhere as well that now it is resorting to multiple URL's to check. What do you think would be the feasible way to do this, without any hardware. Just a regular server and domain from godaddy. I'm thinking getting a Cloud based DNS, which redirects all queries to a directory of its choice. Does this seem right ? And then the captive portal would be forced to open this path

Comment: I don't think it's possible, unless your regular server is a hop on the network, where all packets from clients pass thru - like a router/bridge/firewall. That way you can manipulate the HTTP response from any domain. For example, return a HTTP 302 and the "Location" header to make the browser redirect the user to the captive portal.

Comment: Hey can you accept my request on sky,pe. Will really super appreciate it. Will update this page also if it works